# NGINX reverse proxy setting display the default page ONLY

Tags: nginx

This is my virtual-host configuration at sites-available - [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

        location /?(.*) {
                proxy_pass $scheme://localhost:3002/?$args;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Linked to sites-enabled

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

        location /?(.*) {
                proxy_pass $scheme://localhost:3002/?$args;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

This is my configuration at conf.d - [www.example.com.conf](http://www.example.com.conf)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

        location /?(.*) {
                proxy_pass $scheme://localhost:3002/?$args;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

It only display the default NGINX page running on port 80

Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.

What seems to be wrong on the configuration files!